# 22.04 duplicity backup failed with an exception!

Tags: backup, 22.04, duplicity

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/home/khteh/.local/bin/duplicity", line 87, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/home/khteh/.local/bin/duplicity", line 70, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/home/khteh/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1564, in main
    action = commandline.ProcessCommandLine(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/khteh/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 1241, in ProcessCommandLine
    config.backend = backend.get_backend(args[0])
  File "/home/khteh/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 223, in get_backend
    obj = get_backend_object(url_string)
  File "/home/khteh/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 209, in get_backend_object
    return factory(pu)
  File "/home/khteh/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/duplicity/backends/pydrivebackend.py", line 36, in __init__
    import httplib2
  File "/home/khteh/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from . import auth
  File "/home/khteh/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httplib2/auth.py", line 20, in <module>
    auth_param_name = token.copy().setName("auth-param-name").addParseAction(pp.downcaseTokens)
 AttributeError: module 'pyparsing' has no attribute 'downcaseTokens'
```

https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/1971655

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 my backup was also giving this error. Fixed by re-selecting (refreshing) the backup location in the backup location preferences.